# How can I modify $\frac{\cos(x)+1}{2}$ so that the range does not include 0?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find a bijection between $[0,\infty)$ and $(0,1]$. All I've come up with so far is the below function which has a range of $[0, 1]$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos(x)+1}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

Is there a way I can restrict the range of the function so that it does not include 0?

EDIT: I realize now that my function only worked for the domain $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Your attempt has little to do with a bijection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That which makes the result zero is when $cos(x)+1=0$.  Therefore, multiply both the numerator and denominator by $cos(x)+1$ (multiplying by one) and all zero results will be holes in the graph.

Comment: Nice. I've marked this as the answer now since it addresses the original question.

Comment: Even if we eliminate those points it is not a bijection from $[0,\infty) \to (0,1]$ as the OP is requiring.

Comment: Thois won't make it a bijection from $[0, \infty)\to(0, 1]$. It will make it a function from $[0, \infty)\setminus\{(2n+1)\pi\mid n\in \Bbb N\}$ to $(0, 1]$ which is very much not injective.

Answer (score 3):

$e^{-x}$ will do the job. I don't think you can modify your function to get an answer.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I didn't think of putting a negative in front of the power when I was thinking of that.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you consider\begin{array}{ccc}[0,+\infty)&\longrightarrow&(0,1]\\x&\mapsto&\dfrac1{1+x^2}\end{array}instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your intervals are both closed in one end and open in the other. That means that it's usually a good idea to try to map the closed end to the closed end and the open end to the open end. If you just draw a graph of such a function, you should be able to get ideas for what kinds of functions let you do that; a monotonic  function with $f(0) = 1$ and, if you excuse the abuse of notation, "$f(\infty) = 0$" (technically it's written $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = 0$).

I would personally have gone for $\frac1{x+1}$ as a first attempt, but the other suggestions you've gotten are equally good.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In the future, I will find the advice very helpful.

Comment: You probably mean $\frac1{x+1}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac{\cos(x)+1}{2}$$

is not injective onto $[0,+\infty)$ therefore is not a suitable function to obtain the result.

What about $$1-\frac2{\pi}\arctan x$$